# Can I map the Mac keys Command and Ctrl keys to the same key on a PC keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I really want to use ctrl in order to ctrl-c and ctrl-v but i want to use ctrl-r also for reverse-search in the terminal

By default, you do command-c and command-v for copy-paste, but you do ctrl-r for reverse-search.

Can I make them be the same key just like on Windows?

Comment: You can redefine shortcut keys in the Keyboard pref pane, and you can do it so it only applies in certain apps, if you only want this in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the Command and Ctrl keys on OSX. Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys:

[image]

Comment: That swaps them, I want to use the same key as expected behavior from a PC keyboard.